# Преобразовать бит в массив с данным, либо перебрать его побитово

Tags: массивы, c

День добрый! Есть некая переменная, в которой хранится байт данных. Никак не могу понять как в цикле перебрать этот байт побитово. Пришла мысля(не знаю насколько адекватная) перегнать этот байт в массив[8] и уже этот массив перебрать в `for(;;){}`

Comment: уф! выкрутился такой конструкцией

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {

 a[i] = nes.data[0] & (1 << i); 
 if (a[i]&(1<<i))a[i]=0b1;
}

пора бы уже плотненько посидеть с книжками, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу приведу пример кода:

```
int a = 10;
bool mas[32];

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    mas[i] = a & (1 << i);
}
```

Здесь 32 - число бит в переменной, & - операция бинарного умножения и << - операция бинарного сдвига.
Таким образом мы просто выполняем операцию бинарного умножения для самого числа и определенного бита, что позволяет нам выяснить его значение.

Comment: +1, но я заменил бы константу 32 на 

    CHAR_BIT * sizeof(your variable here)

Answer (score 2):

[@baralgin1003](/users/6349/baralgin1003), вот набор операций с битами для машин с 8-ми битными байтами и маленькая демка.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CLRBIT(u,n) ((u) &= ~(1LL<<(n)))
#define SETBIT(u,n) ((u) |= (1LL<<(n)))
#define TSTBIT(u,n) ((u) & (1LL<<(n)))

#define XCLRBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] &= ~(1 << (_i & 7)); })
#define XSETBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] |= (1 <<  (_i & 7)); })
#define XTSTBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] & (1 << (_i & 7)); })

int
main ()
{
  puts ("uint64_t bits example");
  uint64_t x = 0;  // clear all bits

  SETBIT(x,0);
  SETBIT(x,1);
  SETBIT(x,62);
  SETBIT(x,63);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);
  CLRBIT(x,1);
  CLRBIT(x,62);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);
  if (!TSTBIT(x,62))
    printf("bit 62 is cleared\n");
  if (TSTBIT(x,0))
    printf("bit 0 is set\n");
  SETBIT(x,30 + 2);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);

  puts("char[] bits example");
  char p[256];
  int j;
  memset(p, -1, sizeof(p)); // set all bits

  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(p) * 8;)
    XCLRBIT(p, j++);

  XSETBIT(p, --j);
  if (XTSTBIT(p, j))
    printf ("bit %d (in p[%d]) is set\n", j, j / 8);
  XSETBIT(p, 0);

  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(p); j++)
    if (p[j])
      printf ("p[%d]: 0x%02x\n", j, (unsigned char)p[j]);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc bits.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
uint64_t bits example
c000000000000003
8000000000000001
bit 62 is cleared
bit 0 is set
8000000100000001
char[] bits example
bit 2047 (in p[255]) is set
p[0]: 0x01
p[255]: 0x80
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Макросы `CLRBIT`, `SETBIT` и `TSTBIT` для работы с битами в переменных целого типа (в т.ч. `char` и `unsigned char`, а `XCLRBIT`, `XSETBIT` и `XTSTBIT` (переименуйте сами, я обычно как-то долго придумываю подходящие названия) для работы с битами, упакованными в байтовые массивы произвольного размера.

Comment: Спасибо! сейчас попробую их заюзать

Comment: А почему не [`CHAR_BIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5516044/276994)? Я бы написал как-то так:

    inline void xsetbit(char* s, unsigned i)
    {
        s[i / CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (i % CHAR_BIT));
    }

(заодно оставаясь в рамках стандартного C99).

(Заодно и уйдёт проблема, когда `s` — массив не `char`'ов, а например `long`'ов.)

Comment: @VladD, можно и так. Я же просто грепнул -R в своем коде и приписал короткую демку.

Comment: @avp: И то правда :-)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать гораздо элегантнее при помощи union.

```
struct BIT_INFO{
    unsigned b0: 1;
    unsigned b1: 1;
    unsigned b2: 1;
    unsigned b3: 1;
    unsigned b4: 1;
    unsigned b5: 1;
    unsigned b6: 1;
    unsigned b7: 1;
}

union BitFields_t{
   uint8_t uint_value;
   struct bit_values;
}

   // Обьявляем
   union BitFields_t bit_fields;

   // записываем данные
   bit_fields.uint_value = 15;  // Записали число uint8_t

   // Получаем доступ к битам
  if (bit_fields.bit_values.b0) return 5; // что то делаем
```

Аналогично для других типов.

Так же можно записывать и читать эти биты или величины - в зависимости от поля union к которому обратишься.

Единственный минус - данная фишка платформозависима и на разных архитектурах будет работать по разному, в зависимости от endian Вашего процессора.

Answer (score 0):

что то не получается.
у меня есть такая структура:

```
volatile struct
{
  volatile unsigned char state;
  unsigned char data[1], dat_bit;
} nes;
```

нужный байт лежит в data[1], прогоняя его

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
b = nes.data & (1 << i);
}
```

b у меня unsigned char, так как в avr studio нет булева типа. компилятор ругается на 
invalid operands to binary & (have 'volatile unsigned char *' and 'int')

Comment: Вместо nes.data Вам надо написать nes.data[0].

--

А какой глубокий смысл в 2-х volatile?  Думаете это будет более убедительно для компилятора?

Comment: Совершенно точно. Обращаясь nes.data вы обращаетесь к указателю на первый элемент массива. Поэтому Вам надо либо разыменовать указатель, либо обратиться к элементу по его индексу.

Comment: кстати, так и сделал. вроде заработало, только в каждом элементе теперь данные типа b[1] 00000001, b[2] 0, b[3] 00000100 
а надо b[1] 1, b[2] 0, b[3] 1

Comment: @baralgin1003, зачем Вам массив `unsigned char b[8]` ума не приложу, но если очень хочется, то напишите

    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      b[7 - j] = XTSTBIT(nes.data, j)? 1 : 0;

Comment: еще раз повторюсь, решил такой конструкцией 
for (int i = 8; i >= 0; --i) if ((nes.data[0] & (1 << i))&(1<<i))a[i]=0b1;

не знаю насколько моя правильна, но завтра попробую вашей